# Git, workflow. Implement feature, merge with own fork, do pull-request. Sync with original independent of feature acceptance

Tags: git, github, workflow, fork, pull-request

i dont know how to work with *maybe* acceptable pull requests.

What i want:
implement my **OWN** project version, and extract some overall useful features for pull-requests to **Original** project, but still have all the features in my **OWN** fork, **independent** of pull-request acceptance. And at the same time, keep my **OWN** fork synced with the **Original** project.
I did some branch for overall-useful feature. Pushed it to my fork on github. From that fork i did the pull-request (github web-ui compare and pullrequest)
The request was accepted. But after pull from original project, i have now **2** commits of the feature in my history. One from accepted pull-request, one from my merge at implementing time.
So how to realize it, without doulbe commits after acceptance, and with having the feature in my OWN project in case of **not**-acceptance of my pull request?

Comment: After the change was accepted, did your pull command produce a merge commit or did it rebase your OWN commits on top of the Original project?

Comment: i think merge (but not sure, how to check it?), because i update sometimes my **OWN** project by pulling from **Original** project branch and merge conflicts, if needed.